# Dealing with the result of a fetch() call in React

Tags: reactjs, async-await, fetch

I'm attempting to create a Login page for a React Client app with an Express backend.

```js
// Except from App.js in Client

  async function performLogin (values) {
    const { email:username, password } = values;
    const credentials = { username, password };
    const response = await fetch('http://localhost:4000/tokens/', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: new Headers({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/text',
      }),
      body: JSON.stringify(credentials)
    });
    console.log('Result from backend token: '+JSON.stringify(response));
  };
```

```js
// tokens.js from backend

const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const findUser = require('../lib/find-user');

const signature = process.env.SIGNATURE;
const expiresIn = process.env.EXPIRESIN;

const createToken = (user) =>
  jwt.sign(
    { userId: user.id },
    signature,
    { expiresIn: expiresIn }
  );

// Code used to respond to /tokens/ path

let createTokenRoute = (req,res) => {
  let credentials = req.body;
  console.log('Credentials: '+JSON.stringify(credentials));
  let user = findUser.byCredentials(credentials);
  console.log('User: '+JSON.stringify(user));
  if (user) {
    let token = createToken(user);
    res.status(201);
    console.log('Token: '+JSON.stringify(token));
    res.send(token);
  } else {
    res.sendStatus(422);
  }
};
```

When the `/tokens/` path is pinged from Postman, I get a returned token as text, as expected, and the backend's console dutifully spits out:

```
Credentials: {"username":"rd@example.com","password":"12345678"}
User: {"id":"3","username":"rd@example.com","name":"Richard","password":"12345678"}
Token: "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c... etc."
```

and Postman shows me the expected result:

```
eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c... etc.
```

However, when called from the `App.js` code, the backend behaves as before, listing Credentials, User, and Token... but the Client's Browser console gives me back an empty object:

```
Result from backend token: {}
```

I've tried the `Accept` header, but my ignorance won't let me see where I'm going wrong. I'm fairly sure it's something entirely stupid ;-)

---

Edit:

So I rewrote the `performLogin` function:

```js
  async function performLogin (values) {
    const { email:username, password } = values;
    const credentials = { username, password };
    const response = await fetch('http://localhost:4000/tokens/', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: new Headers({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/text',
      }),
      body: JSON.stringify(credentials)
    });
    const result = await response.json();
    console.log('Result from backend token: '+result);
  };
```

and the page now crashes...

```
Unhandled Rejection (SyntaxError): The string did not match the expected pattern.
(anonymous function)
src/App.js:55
  52 |     }),
  53 |     body: JSON.stringify(credentials)
  54 |   });
> 55 |   const result = await response.json();
     | ^  56 |   console.log('Result from backend token: '+result);
  57 | };
  58 | 
View compiled
```

Comment: the issue is with fetch. Look at `fetch.json()` to parse it, instead of using JSON.Stringify.

Comment: Hmmm, not sure about that. See amended question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`send response as json from backend`

res.status(201).json({ token : token });

`Accept json from front end`

'Accept': 'application/json'